# Variable watchpoint doesn't work in Eclipse/ADT Android projects

Tags: android, eclipse

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    int field = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        int local = 0;
        field = local;
        local = field;
    }
}
```

I've put "watchpoint" on "field" and in "Breakpoint Properties" I confirmed that both access and modification are being watched. But the watchpoint didn't trigger the debugger to pause execution of program. Tried both in 2.2 AVD and on Desire with USB Debugging enabled.
Anyone has experience on how watchpoint works with Android?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't find an official google source that says that it does not work. However I keep finding mirrors of this document
http://www.milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/debugger.html which says

> Known Issues and Limitations - Most of the optional features JDWP allows are not implemented. These include field access watchpoints and better tracking of monitors.

Comment: I'll take this for now. Thanks!

Comment: It's been more than 3 years since this answer was published, is there any news about field watchpoint support in Dalvik VM?

Comment: it is not supported till the debugger not using the checkmark sign on watchpoint. [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630643/android-debugging-watch-points#comment5094500_4630643)