# Android debugging - Watch points

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to use watchpoints to debug an Android problem in Eclipse.  I'm settings a watchpoint by settings a breakpoint on my variable definition.  However the execution never pauses even though the variable is accessed.  Has anyone else come across this problem?  Could someone please try setting a watch point on a variable in an Android project and see if it works?

Thanks

Comment: Variable watchpoints are supported by JDWP but not by Android, so Eclipse doesn't let you set them.  Breakpoints are fully supported.  Make sure the round bullet icon turns into a bullet-with-a-checkmark icon when the debugger connects to your app; if it doesn't, it means Eclipse couldn't figure something out and the breakpoint hasn't been set.

Comment: @fadden, you totally should post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the app as debug? Is debug set to true in your manifest?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a handset, make sure USB debugging is enabled.

[Heres](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8C-O51n7B8) a handy how-to video.